# Display Messed Up

Tags: centos, virtualbox, display-settings

I'm trying to make the screen expand so I'm not left with any of the grey space at the sides, but I'm not sure how I can adjust the display while having the font and everything else the same size. I had it right before but I'm not sure what I did to mess up the settings for it to become like this. Can anyone help?

[image: The picture is displayed below.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the guest addition that you need to install on your CentOS machine: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox/CentOSguest